# How to pause/resume a DispatchWorkItem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this object:

```
lockWallTask = DispatchWorkItem(block: {
        self.lockWall()
    })
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10, execute: lockWallTask)
```

So it is executing after 10 seconds. However, I am trying to pause this item and then resume it. For instance:

I would pause the item after 3 seconds, meaning there is 7 seconds left for execution. I do other stuff for like 5 minutes and then I **resume the item and there is still 7 seconds left for execution.** I was trying to achieve this life this:

```
DispatchQueue.resume(task)

DispatchQueue.suspend(task)
```

However, I was given this compile error:

[image]

I don't understand that error. The variable ***task*** is of type 'DispatchWorkItem'

**How would I achieve pausing, or suspending, a DispatchWorkItem and then resuming it?**

Comment: try `DispatchQueue.main.resume()`

Comment: Wouldn't that resume and suspend all the DispatchObjects? I have several objects running @AdrianBobrowski

Comment: yes it suspend and resume all tasks in this `DispatchQueue`

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski it wouldn't work for me. I only want to suspend one object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `DispatchSource` timer where you can pause, resume and stop and perform your operation accordingly.

```
var timer: DispatchSource?

func resumeTimer() {
    guard let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: DispatchSource.TimerFlags(rawValue: 0), queue: mainQueue) as? DispatchSource else { return }
    timer.setEventHandler {
        mainQueue.async(execute: { [weak self] in
            self?.runTimer()
        })
    }
    timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now(), interval: .seconds(10), leeway: .seconds(1))
    timer.resume()
}

func pausedTimer() {
    if let timer = timer {
        timer.suspend()
    }
}

func stoppedTimer() {
    if let timer = timer {
        timer.cancel()
    }
}
```